# Matrices with entries from non-associative, non-commutative, and non-unital algebras over a commutative ring

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, reference-request, noncommutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a commutative ring, and $A$ a possibly non-associative, non-commutative algebra, and non-unital algebra over $K$.

I'm curious about matrices and linear algebra over such general $K$-algebras, and I'm wondering whether there are some good references for this? Happy for references just for the associative but non-commutative case as well.

Weibel's Homological Algebra book discusses this a little bit in section 7.1, e.g. that if $A$ is associative but non-commutative, then the trace must take values in $A/[A,A]$ so that it is invariant under change of basis.

Comment: There is very little to say about such things, so there is not much in the form of references to give!

Comment: In any case, Google should find papers about algebras of matrices over alternative algebras, for example example, or Jordan algebras. This is very far from what you want ---arbitrary algebras!--- but should serve as a guide to how difficult this is.

Comment: Linear algebra is usually interested a ring of endomorphisms of an abelian group, the operation being composition of such endomorphisms, hence being associative.  The ring of matrices over a not-associative ring is not-associative.  I'm not saying there's nothing interesting to say, just that this is why it's not a very well-trodden path.